# How to add several list params to link_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have the model `kit` which `has_and_belongs_to_many` `products`.

**I want to add all of the `product_ids` the kit has into a link_to path.**

```
<%= link_to "<button>Personalizar este pack</button>".html_safe, kit_builder_path(kit_id: @kit.id, products_ids: @kit.products, kit_name: @kit.name) %>
```

**¿Do I need to loop through the @kit.products ids and inject them?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is what forms are for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
product_ids: @kit.products.collect(&:id)
```